# Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'buttons' does not exist in type 'Settings

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using Angular 8 and following example from [here](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/extensions/buttons)
but

[image]

and the exception is

[image]

Please help me solve this.

Comment: How did you declare dtOptioans?Must be declared as "any", not as "DataTables.Settings":  ```dtOptions: any = {};``` in your class.

Comment: TypeScript is a strictly type language, you must have declared dtOptions: Settings, hence the error. dtOptions should contain all the properties defined in Settings, or make it as any type as suugested.

Answer (score 12):

Just make sure the `dtOptions` is declared as `any`.

You can find this comment on: https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/extensions/buttons

```
// Must be declared as "any", not as "DataTables.Settings"
dtOptions: any = {};
```

Answer (score -1):

If the Type `Settings` has been defined by you or your team, you must add the `buttons` property as:

```
buttons: any[];
```

Or

```
buttons?: any[];
```

To keep retro-compatibilty.

If the type `buttons` has been defined by a third part library, instead, there's something wrong in the way you're using it and you should check the documentation to fix it.

Comment: this was thrown "      Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'buttons' does not exist in type 'Settings'." after adding button property